# Multiple Image Upload System

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to work with uploading multiple images on my project but it is not saving into the database

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //validate
    $this->validate($request, [
        'subject'=>'required|min:10',
        'tags' => 'required',
        'body' => 'required|min:20',
        'filename' => 'sometimes',
        'filename.*' => 'file|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:5000'
    ]);

    //store
    $news=auth()->user()->news()->create($request->all());
    $news->tags()->attach($request->tags);
    $this->storeImage($news);

    //redirect
    return redirect()->route('news.index');
}
```

```php
private function storeImage($news)
{
    if (request()->has('image')) {
        foreach (request()->file('filename') as $file) {
            $news->update([
                'filename' => request()->filename->store('uploads', 'public'),
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

Upload HTML:

```xml
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="image"><b>Select Image To Add</b></label>
  <input type="file" name="filename[]">
</div>
```

How can I make the file save into the database as it is not saving to the database at all? Could anyone help me to solve this problem please?

Comment: Could someone answer me please

Comment: This won't save the images into the database. It will save them in the storage folder.

Comment: @IGP how do i solve it?

Comment: First how do you plan on saving images to the DB? Do you have a blob type column? Is anything getting saved at all?

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good idea to save images in the database. Keep the files in your public folder on the server and save the file paths in the database only.

update your form like this

```
<form class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="/store-image">
```

add **multiple** to the input

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="image"><b>Select Image To Add</b></label>
    <input type="file" name="filename[]" multiple >
</div>
```

update your storeImageFunction Like this

```
public function storeImage(request $request) {
 $input=$request->all();
 $images=array();
 if($files=$request->file('images')){
   foreach($files as $file){
     $name=$file->getClientOriginalName();
     $file->move('image',$name);
     $images[]=$name;
  }
 }
}
```

Now, you have got all the image paths in the **images array**.